# Successor for Cherry G80-3000LQCDE-2 keyboard?

Tags: keyboards

I wanted to buy a second Cherry G80-3000LQCDE-2 keyboard for the workplace because I have been very comfortable using it at home for years. However I noticed that it is not available any more, at least in Germany. Can someone shed light on why it was discontinued and what similar (preferably Cherry) keyboard I can get instead? It should be mechanical, affordable, with pressure point (not linear) switches and not too loud. Not bells and whistles, just a keyboard with German layout.

According to https://deskthority.net/wiki/Cherry_G80-3000, the Q in the LQCDE identifier stands for clear switches so I would prefer ones with similar feel but, if possible, less typing noise.
https://www.cherry.de/PDF/DE_G80-3000.pdf does not show this type anymore, however, it only lists ones with black, blue and brown switches. Which ones are more most suitable for my requirements?

I paid 55 € for my old one and don't want to spend much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I think they just made a new keyboard for that series of products. If you look at **Cherry Americas** website you can find a G80-3000 MX, which looks really similar to the product you said. But if you want that specific product you can easily find it on Amazon, as I already did.

Comment: On Amazon in Germany it is unfortunately not available anymore, see https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B000TNEVBC. The G80-3000 MX keybaords all look the same but the problem is that the switches are different.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for that, as I don't live in Germany I use to look at Amazon.com and not Amazon.de website. Can you take a look at this: https://www.amazon.de/Cherry-G80-3000-Tastaturen-Schwarz-Standard/dp/B0041KJKAG/ ? It says it's available in Germany

Comment: The keyboard you link has blue switches (too loud) and a UK layout (although the image shows a DE layout).

Comment: Ok, let's change brand. I found Corsair STRAFE (red switches) to be very quiet, here is the Amazon link https://www.amazon.de/Corsair-Keyboard-Gaming-STRAFE-CH-9000088-/dp/B011102VSQ , unfortunately it's not cheap and it's designed for gaming purposes

Comment: @boxHiccup red are linear. If he wants tactile and quiet he wants brown or clear switches.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of my old G80-8200, which you can find on ebay.de for around the price you're buying at.

[image]

If you can get past the useless card scanner, there's a lot to like about this keyboard - fully reprogrammable keys, lots of extra function keys you can assign stuff to, and lots of clear caps so you can define your own illustrations for your caps. In addition, there are editions of this keyboard which come with the excellent Brown switches, which as others have noted, are similar to your clears. Of course, since these are Cherry MX switches we're talking about, keep in mind that if you MUST have clear switches, it's possible to [buy a switch set](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Genuine-CHERRY-MX-Clear-Keyswitch-Microswitch-Keyboard-Mechanical-Switches-/111964563817?hash=item1a119ba969:g:iuUAAOSwn51UY4C4) and [swap out the old switches for your new clear set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GivKt63dLvA).